# Regex PCRE expression

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a piece of html code like the following one:

```
<td width="24%"><b>Something</b></td>
          <td width="1%"></td>
          <td width="46%" align="center">
           <p><b>
    needed
  value</b></p>
          </td>
          <td width="28%" align="center">
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
```

What is a good regex pattern to extract the first text node (not tags but the text inside) after the word `Something` I mean I want to extract

```
     needed
  value
```

and nothing more.

I cant figure out a working regex pattern in php.

**EDIT:**
I am not parsing whole html document but few lines of it so all I want is to do it using Regex and no HTML parsers.

Comment: Don't parse HTML using a regular expression. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) on why.

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: thank you for the answers. I know regex is not the proper way to do it but the only thing I am parsing is "needed value" so I think it is an overkill for this task to use Html parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring potential issues parsing HTML with regex, the following pattern should match your example code:

```
Something(?:(?:<[^>]+>)|\s)*([\w\s*]+)
```

This will match `Something`, followed by any list of HTML tags (or whitespace) and match the very next block of text, `\w` (including whitespace).

You can use this in PHP's `preg_match()` method like this:

```
if (preg_match('/Something(?:(?:<[^>]+>)|\s)*([\w\s*]+)/', $inputString, $match)) {
    $matchedValue = $match[1];
    // do whatever you need
}
```

Regex Explained:

```
Something         # has to start with 'Something'
(?:               # non-matching group
    (?:           # non-matching group
        <[^>]+>   # any HTML tags, <...>
    )
    | \s          # OR whitespace
)*                # this group can match 0+ times
(
    [\w\s*]+      # any non-HTML words (with/without whitespace)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That was all I needed. I find the explanation very useful too.